# .Net project try to load unused assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I'm taking over a .Net project which is composed (the solution) of 7 projects.
Two of them consist of the main project, so the user interface and the admin interface. I managed to run the user interface buti'm still blocked on the admin one.

Here's the structure of the solution:

- Solution

  - UserInterface
  - AdminInterface

The problem is that the Admin project failed because it is trying to reference the user interface assembly, even if it's not in the project references and there is no other reference to that assembly. Where should I look to check why is it trying to load that assembly and remove it?

Comment: It could try to load an assembly literally anywhere in the codebase. You need to prove a lot more information here. How are you "blocked"? Does it compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it dance a little jig?

Answer (score 1):

Try searching on Project -> "projectname" properties -> References and clic on Unused References to delete the references that you don't use in the project.